# Bootstrap: .img-responsive changes order of images from horizontal to vertical

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm redoing my non-responsive website with Bootstrap, just to learn.

I did almost everything until now, but cannot get four images to be responsive and stay where the should be.

**This is the end result I want to achieve:**

[image]

**What I have:**

[image]

I've used the: `class="img-responsive center-block"` class.

This is my Bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/ksrPd5iBSR

I would be very grateful for any hint.

Comment: use display:inline-block in css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`center-block` has a property `display: block` which is aligning the images vertically as default behavior of block is to occupy full width of space.

Add a `text-center` class to the parent container to align it in center. Add a custom class with `display: inline-block` for the images.

[**Updated Bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/1vJ4grvarc)

Comment: You have used: `align-inline` instead of `display: inline-block`. It is the same? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `align-inline` is just a name :) You should be worried about the property inside it. Changes can be made to the class name. Even you can target the `img` directly. `a img { display: inline-block; }`

Comment: Upps, I see, you have used some custom CSS. I thought it was a bootstrap class or somthing. Just 1 more question: In your bootply (and in mine) the images arent smaller as I resize the window. Is the `.img-responsive` not working?

Comment: It works. But you will need to setup a width for the parent container. Try adding a grid class to the parent. The images will adjust according to the width. Currently, there is no restriction for the icons to resize. Even you can try replacing the icon with bigger image, It would resize according to the browser window width.

Comment: May you update your bootply, please. I've tried using this grid class in the div containing the images: `col-md-4`, but the images display vertically.

Comment: In the case of preserving the horizontal alignment. Add the grid classes to image itself: http://www.bootply.com/XBF55Ma86u